# Android, back button deallocates Activity memory?

Tags: android, memory, garbage-collection

I made a simple app to test the memory of Android.
It has two Activities, A and B.
A is a simple Activity with a button that starts B.
B consists of a pretty big image (jpg, 1024x768 pixel in mdpi)

When I monitor this process using DDMS, heap goes up as expected when moving from A to B.
When I press (hardware, or software using `super.onBackPressed()`) button on B and end up in A again, the heap does not shrink again, even after calling garbage collection. Is this expected? Will the memory taken up by B ever be released during the lifetime of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the garbage collector works "*nondeterministic*". In particular, even a call to the garbage collector does not mean that the memory is completely freed. It is only guaranteed that the memory is freed if more memory is requested.

Answer (score 3):

**onBackPressed()** just pop your B Activity from the **[BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)** then your Activity is no longer visible(onStop() called)to you, but it's process have'nt been killed untill the Os need it's memory

Comment: I guess this and Dan's answer both are correct. I'll just assume that if heap space increases with every visit to activity B from the second one on, that could likely mean memory leaks.

Comment: If you run into an OutOfMemoryException after some switches from A to B and back, then you should hunt for a memory leak.